# Regular expression for getting any letter, symbol, number from 1 to 100 maxlength

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

As you can read in the tittle i need a regular expression for getting any letter, symbol, number from 1 to 100 maxlength (any text posible). Can someone provide that for me and maybe a good link to understand how it works.
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by *getting* such data?

Comment: What do you define as a symbol? You can use `.{1,100}` to match any text, but that will include *any* characters except newlines.

Comment: Give some sample valid and invalid inputs to make it a little more clear (it's not very clear right now).

Comment: the solution given by LBushkin and codaddict worked perfectly, it was a RegularExpressionValidator i needed to use instead of a RequiredFieldValidator because the RequiredFieldValidator was giving me conflicts with an custom control (CustomTextBox) i used at work.
  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match ***any text possible*** of maxlength 100 you can use:

```
.{1,100}
```

to even match newlines you can use:

```
[\d\D]{1,100}
```

Notes:

- `.` : A metachar that matches
  anything but a newline.
- `{1,100}`: min of 1 and max of 100 of
  the previous pattern
- `[]`: the char class
- `\d`: any digit
- `\D`: any non-digit
- `[\d\D]`: any char

Answer (score 2):

I've found decent reference [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for years.  It's pretty generic & aimed at getting you to use their tools, but it's still a good reference.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to piece it together from here:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/prasad_1/RegExpPSD12062005021717AM/RegExpPSD.aspx

here's the MSDN start page for regex:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30wbz966%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you don't really need a regular expression to do this.

```
var test = "test";
var result = test.Substring(0, test.Length<100 ? test.Length : 100);
```